# why does pyzbar remove some digits from the barcode?

Tags: python, barcode-scanner

the code is of type Interleaved code 2 of 5 (I25), and whenever I try to read it, the output always removes the number after the "`-`", leaving the code invalid, and in banking applications, it does not remove the digits .

```
        image = cv2.imread('code.pgn')
        barcodes = decode(image)
        for barcode in barcodes:
            (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        barcode_data = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
        print('barcode_data')
```

the original barcode is like this:

[image: BARCODE]

this is a barcode from brazil, and when python-barcode read it, the detected type is I25

the output looks like this:

```
82620000000610200097000784066170100072722015 (I25)
```

so if i create another barcode with these numbers from the output it doesnt work

Comment: As far as I can tell, I25 barcodes are incapable of representing anything other than digits, so I have no idea what those dashes you're showing are supposed to be.

Comment: @jasonharper notice the missing `4` at the end of the output. This is what is missing after all dashes.

Comment: But where are the dashes coming from?  They can't actually be part of the barcode, as I25 only does digits.  Perhaps they're just formatting, added to make the human-readable numbers printed below many barcodes more meaningful - but that doesn't explain the missing digits.  Perhaps your barcodes aren't actually I25, but some variant that somehow adds some additional symbols - I cannot find any mention of such a symbology, but that doesn't rule out the possibility of some rare/proprietary version.  Any chance you can post an actual image of a barcode?

Comment: @jasonharper well, when I read it, the type that python-barcode identifies is i25

Comment: @jasonharper I edited my question and put an image of the barcode

Comment: I get exactly the same results when I scan it,  And I've manually decoded the right end of the barcode, the final digits are indeed 15 - the dash and following digit simply do not exist in the barcode, only in the human-readable text.  So the problem with your duplicated barcode not working must be something else.  Are you sure you're using I25 for the output?  Are you sure you're using it correctly - for example, barcode fonts typically require specific characters to be added before and after the actual content, to produce the required start/stop codes...

Comment: (continued) Does the output visually match the original - I25 has no room for any variation, they should be bar-for-bar identical.  What sort of hardware is scanning the barcode - perhaps it can't handle a barcode that's scaled significantly larger or smaller than it's expecting.

Comment: @jasonharper well, I'm printing the code type, and it reads as I25 and if I have to add something else, like characters, I really have no idea what or which ones

Comment: @jasonharper I'm sorry, I made a mistake. it's not the python-barcode I used to decode, it's pyzbar

Comment: I suppose the barcode format is actually DUN-14/ITF-14 and not I25. Not sure if it's a limitation with pyzbar. Edit: Just tested on a simillar barcode ('boleto' from Brazil) and also didn't work for me.

Comment: Btw, the dashes don't mean anything. That particular type of barcode is number only.